# AD authentication for ICINGA

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap, icinga

Hi I am trying to authenticate icinga(centos) using AD in the same VPC.But failed in every attempt. Is it not possible to use AD authentication for ICINGA? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like http://host/icinga than icinga web panel, basically, by default, uses apache server as background. So, you can configure apache config.
Something like:

```
ScriptAlias /icinga/cgi-bin "/usr/local/icinga/sbin"
```

Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all

```
AuthName "USE YOUR WINDOWS ACCOUNT"
AuthType NTLM
NTLMAuth on
NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp --require-membership-of=S-x-5-21-1343024091-1284227242-725345543-42388 --domain=YOURDOMAIN"
NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! and sorry for the delay. Let me check it.